# content has been hidden after position absolute

Tags: css

content has been hidden after position absolute<

position absolute be hide my content

i want my content to be border 5px

but after type this code my content has been hidden

see: http://qass.im/checked

```
.wrapper > ul {
list-style: none;
position: relative;
z-index:1;
clear:both;
border:5px solid #ccc;
}

.wrapper > ul > li {
position: absolute;
left:0;
top:0;
width: 100%;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Absolutely positioned elements don't affect the height of their containers. If your `<li>`s are positioned absolutely, you need to manually give your `<ul>` a height that's big enough to hold them, or else it will think its height is 0 because as far as it knows there aren't any contents inside of it. Change your css for the `<ul>` to this, and then modify the height until you get something that works as you want it to:

```
.wrapper > ul {
    list-style: none;
    position: relative;
    z-index:1;
    clear:both;
    border:5px solid #ccc;
    height:30px; /* Added this line to create a space for the <li>s */
}
```

NOTE: You may also need to change the `top` and `left` on your `<li>`s to account for the border.

Comment: but i dont want height!

Comment: Then don't use absolute positioning.